# Are questions about when stories are set not fit for Sci-fi & Fantasy SE?

Tags: discussion, scope, specific-question

I recently asked a question about when Beauty and the Beast was set, it has since been moved to the Movie and TV SE site, [here](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/1733/1074).

Are questions of this sort not fit for this SE site?

Comment: As I said in chat, I don't think it's any different from asking when Star Wars or Harry Potter is set, aside from the people determining whether it's on topic, or off. I think if you're going to migrate Beauty and the Beast for being off topic because it's "not for adults", you should migrate Harry Potter too. Note, I'd never advocate migrating HP, just playing Devil's advocate. :)

Comment: My other question on B&B hasn't been migrated.

Comment: And that's what I mean. Inconsistency doesn't help anyone. I think BatB is on topic; it's a representation of a traditional fairy tale, and those are really the precursors to all fantasy.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the problem is to determine if it's on or off topic, **because it's on topic.**

I think it was ***migrated*** because the question was better suited to [movies.stackexchange](http://movies.stackexchange.com). i.e. The question will be more likely be to answered (or found interesting to answer) by a movies expert than by a Sci-fi expert.

Migrating question is not a trivial decision, it's highly suggestive. There is a huge, blurry overlap between Sci-Fi StackExchange and the movies & literature StackExchange. As an example, I was surprised when [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13466/how-were-r2d2-and-c3po-made?noredirect=1) was migrated. But It's true that it ***may*** fit better on movies.stackexchange.

Therefore, I urge Mods to be more cautious when migrating question. As the last word, I will quote [this recent blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/).

> But focus on the questions that aren’t on-topic, or aren’t getting answered – snatching someone’s question (or answer) away without any forewarning is a slap in their face.

Comment: +1 for the quote. I would argue that my question is more likely to be answered here, though it doesn't help that the Movie/Lit sites are still in beta and may end up being more suited. For example a Sci-fi/Fant' expert might find corrleation between it and other adaptations (not film ones) and make an answer from that. As such it may as well have been migrated to the Lit.se sight.