# Migration policies

Tags: discussion, scope, migration

Following [this question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1657/are-questions-about-when-stories-are-set-not-fit-for-sci-fi-fantasy-se), it became evident that there is 2 stackexchange beta that particularly overlaps scifi.stackexchange scope :

- https://movies.stackexchange.com/
- https://literature.stackexchange.com/

There's a [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/) that offer some guideline on the subject of migration, but I think we should decide, as a community :

1. What kind of question we should migrate (generals rules).
2. How we will decide which question to migrate (which process we will follow before migrating a question.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. *What kind of questions we should migrate*: Ones that are a good question, but not appropriate for our site.  Generally, this means questions that are properly formatted for Stack Exchange (meets the criteria for practical, specific, not too localized, etc.), but which don't actually relate to science fiction or fantasy (e.g. off-topic).  If they are off-topic for us, but not off-topic for another site, they should be *candidates* for migration.
2. *How will we decide which questions to migrate (which process will we follow before migrating a question)*: Users should Vote To Close (if they have the reputation), and flag a moderator asking that is be considered for migration.  The moderators will then, if they agree that it is a good candidate for migration, contact the moderators of the target SE site, and ask if the question would be appropriate for migrating.  This step is important, because the moderators of the other site will be better judges of whether it is on topic for them, and will also have a better idea of whether it may be a duplicate on their site.  There's no point in migrating a question if it will just get closed after it is migrated.

Comment: As an addition to this, I would only consider questions not related to the *genre* of Sci-Fi or Fantasy as well as question relating to the *medium* and not the *content*; such as "How was effect X done?"

Comment: @Pureferret That's more a question of what is and is not on topic for our site, rather than anything specific to migration.

Comment: Then isn't that covered by your first point?

Comment: @Pureferret Yes. Off-topic questions should be considered as potential migration candidates. What is or is not off-topic isn't part of my answer, though, nor should it be.

Comment: Fair enough then. I was just thinking about the reasoning for migration on the recent question about [R2-D2 and C3PO](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13466/how-were-r2d2-and-c3po-made?noredirect=1).